# Is there a Stack Exchange site for digital art applications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

At the very bottom of this page, I can see all sorts of sites, like *[role-playing games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)*, math, and even [bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour), but there is no site for digital art applications (like [Photoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop), [Paint.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET), etc.)!

Is there one, and if so, where?

Comment: Whenever you want to see if certain site exists in the Stack Exchange network, just check this list: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic. You can sort it by name as well to make it more easy to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) might be close to what you're looking for. From the [site's FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Graphic Design is for questions targeted toward 2D design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - Digital media
>   Examples: video, Adobe Flash
>
> but not about:
>
> - Simple "How to" questions
> - Brainstorming or idea gathering
> - Technical questions related to 3D software
> - Technical questions related to video editing software
> - Web site architecture and development
> - Examples: HTML that doesn't include CSS, server-side issues
> - Landscaping and architecture

Please read the rest of the FAQ thoroughly (and earn your [Analytical badge](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/badges/73/analytical)) and browse the site's existing questions before you ask your own.

Comment: Their FAQ page has changed, but I think the answer remains valid.

Answer (score 3):

[Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) might fit some of your questions.

You might also want to check out the [Arts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/1/arts) section of [Area51](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) where you can vote on and propose new stack exchange sites if you have one in mind that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, Stack Exchange has a large number of sites. One of the categories is [Life & Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts-name), but in the Technology category there are other sites that might interest you.

## Life & Arts

[Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/)
Q&A for artists and crafters. See [this page](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/on-topic) for details.

From [Are digital arts on-topic here?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6), questions about tools like Photoshop are off-topic, but questions about general arts and crafts concepts are welcome.

[Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)
Q&A for Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts

The tag [[adobe-photoshop]](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) has more than 8,000 questions.

[Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)
Q&A for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers

The tag [[photoshop]](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) has more than 800 questions.

[Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/)
Q&A for engineers, producers, editors and enthusiasts spanning the fields of video and media creation

The tag [[after-effects]](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-effects) has more than 1,000 questions

## Technology

[Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)
Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games

[Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/)
Q&A for computer graphics researchers and programmers